How to let all displayed formulas be inline style?
Maybe the problem is more out of fun/curiosity, but,
how to make every display formula be of inline style, except for typing \textstyle every time?
One possible solution is \everydisplay{\textstyle}, but it causes errors when the document has align and multline environment. \let\displaystyle\textstyle can only change the align and multline environment, but not the equation. (See this post).

Note that for align and the other multi-row displayed equation environments of the amsmath package, it would not be enough to issue various \textstyle directives. In order to properly duplicate the "look" of inline-style math material created by TeX, you will also have to issue \nolimits statements after instructions such as \int, \sum, and \prod, and you will need to reduce the vertical separation between rows to just \baselineskip.
